# phpInfo values different if internal oder external request

Tags: php, apache2.4

I'm working on an own small Apache2 Server at home.
Actually I stuck by changing the upload_max_size (what I've finally done on all php.ini files (apache2/ cli/ cgi/...yes I know I shouldn't do that).

When I'm open my phpinfo via localIP (192.168.1.11) it shows different values, than when I open the same file in the same folder via ext. IP (dynDNS).

How is it possible?

**Left**: local request **Right**: external request

[image]

Comment: You have different versions of PHP somewhere maybe, or your Apache config is missing something. Can you provide more detail, what do you mean external and local, how are they configured?

Comment: I mean with internal -> local -> IP 192.168.1.11 and external www.domain.com.

Loaded Configuration File on both: etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: how is your Apache set up? How do you access it externally? You have a static IP set? Maybe that's where you should look. PHP doesn't just change its parameters.

Comment: I use Ubuntu Server 14.04 as OS with apache 2.4 on it.
installed PHP5 and mysql server 5.6...set up one virtual Host for "owncloud" and that's it.
I use dynDNS which forward every request to my router and further to my Server.

Comment: Can you execute var_dump($_SERVER), for both requests and post first part, until "Configuration", for both environments?

Comment: Sorry, was quiet busy
Was to long to post it here, so I filled in a file.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52355312/var_dump_server.txt

Comment: The `DOCUMENT_ROOT` differs; are you really serving the same vhost on both requests?